# code visualizer for Racket programs

Tags: python, racket, code-visualization

Is there a code visualization website for Racket programs (for novice [WeScheme](http://wescheme.org/) users) similar to what is available at [Online Python Tutor](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit)? Needless to say, it would provide a great self-teaching or learning tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DrRacket provides a Stepper--it's one of the buttons in the toolbar--that shows the evaluation of programs written in Beginning and Intermediate student languages as a sequence of steps.  Its interface is not as pretty as the page you point to--as the author of the Stepper, I can say this with confidence--but it's a visualization tool along the same lines as the one you describe.

Comment: Thanks, John. How about for novice WeScheme users? What would you suggest for them?

Comment: RE WeScheme: my summer plans will be focused on improving WeScheme.  I hope to integrate **tracer** (http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/tracer/tracer.plt/1/9/planet-docs/tracer/index.html) into WeScheme.  It requires me to build some back-end infrastructure to support it.  It's in the works.

Comment: Tracer is cool! Look forward to having it on WeScheme as well.